# How can I add url's to this list of var quotes?

Tags: javascript, url, var

I'm trying to add individual links to the the var quotes list (Quote test 1, Quote test 2 etc). How can I do this please?

```
<div id="quoteDisplay">
 </div>
 <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>
 
 <script>
 var quotes = [
         'Quote test 1',
         'Quote test 2',
         'Quote test 3',
         'Quote test 4',
         'Quote test 5',
         'Quote test 6',
         'Quote test 7',
         'Quote test 8',
         'Quote test 9',
         'Quote test 10',
         'Quote test 11',
         'Quote test 12',
         'Quote test 13',
         'Quote test 14',
         ]

function newQuote() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
 </script>
```

Comment: if you need to add use `quotes.push(yourCustomLink)`

Answer (score 0):

Create input and create button first and select this input, button on script tag and add onclick event for button. Then read the input value(selectedElement.value) and push to the array.